# Config Error Failed to decrypt attribute 'password'

Tags: iis, encryption, config, application-pool

Module IIS Web Core 
Notification Unknown 
 
Handler Not yet determined 
 
Error Code 0x8007000d  
Config Error Failed to decrypt attribute 'password' 
Config File Unavailable (Config Isolation)

When i run my app im getting this error and i couldn't find any solution please help?

Comment: See this as it resolved my issue

http://serverfault.com/questions/230934/iis-7-5-encryption-keys-and-hresult-0x80090005

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The problem was *C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config* file. In the config file, I deleted username and password definitions for applications and it worked well.

Comment: Awesome!!! I had the same problem--looked at the applicationHost.config file (which BTW is located in Windows 2012 at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) and found which application used a password. I didn't change the config file, but went back into IIS and re-entered the credentials for that app and bingo that updated the config file and it worked.  (BTW, this problem causes ALL apps for a server to fail with this error. What is a bit confusing is the error appears to be a application pool failure, but the password is for the application not the pool--triggered when the pool wakes up.)

Comment: Yes had the same issue and had to re-enter the physical path credentials for each web application. In my case it was to do with Keepass encrypting the password but the hash being wrong for the machine as everything had been copied over from another machine

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after clone a Web Server.

Solution:

Source Server:

```
aspnet_regiis -px "iisConfigurationKey" "C:\temp\iisConfigurationKey.xml" -pri 
aspnet_regiis -px "iisWasKey" "C:\temp\iisWasKey.xml" -pri
```

Destination Server:

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "iisConfigurationKey" "C:\temp\iisConfigurationKey.xml" 
aspnet_regiis -pi "iisWasKey" "C:\temp\iisWasKey.xml"
```

And, at the final, copy `applicationhost.config` from the source server to destination server.

Comment: This worked great on my cloned VM.  aspnet_regiis had to be called from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 on my configuration.  applicationhost.config was located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Note to anyone getting a "rsa key container not found" error, you have to run this as an administrator (in my case this was also due to a cloned Web Server).

Comment: Worked for me too. It didn't seem to at first (maybe I didn't test right), but after a restart of the cloned VM all went well. So, much thanks (and +1).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those mystery errors. For me, the issue occurred when we cloned a development server. When I went to reconfigure some the sites in IIS on the cloned server, one of the sites threw this error. You need to delete all the sites that shared the same app pool in IIS and recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by disabling Anonymous Access in the application, then re-enabling it immediately. No IIS restart necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I changed the Physical Path under the website's advanced settings to a dummy path then changed it back, then it started working.